# Controller Name Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have added a module to my application called `Tokened.rb` and added the `include Tokened` to my model.  However, now when I try to load that model, I get a "NameError in TestingsController#index" error...  I haven't included Tokened in my TestingsController, but not sure why I should or where I should put it.

My code:
`testing.rb`

```
class Testing < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Tokened
end
```

My Tokened.rb module:

```
module Tokened

  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    after_initialize do
      self.token = generate_token if self.token.blank?
    end
  end

  private
    def generate_token
      loop do
        key = SecureRandom.base64(15).tr('+/=lIO0', 'pqrsxyz')
        break key unless self.class.find_by(token: key)
      end
    end
end
```

Finally, my testing controller:

```
  class TestingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_testing, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /testings
  # GET /testings.json
  def index
    @testings = Testing.all
  end

  # GET /testings/1
  # GET /testings/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /testings/new
  def new
    @testing = Testing.new
  end

  # GET /testings/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /testings
  # POST /testings.json
  def create
    @testing = Testing.new(testing_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @testing.save
        format.html { redirect_to @testing, notice: 'Testing was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @testing }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @testing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /testings/1
  # PATCH/PUT /testings/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @testing.update(testing_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @testing, notice: 'Testing was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @testing }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @testing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /testings/1
  # DELETE /testings/1.json
  def destroy
    @testing.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to testings_url, notice: 'Testing was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_testing
      @testing = Testing.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def testing_params
      params.require(:testing).permit(:name, :address, :signature)
    end
end
```

What gives? I am not sure what is going on here and why it needs to be included in the controller.

Comment: provide full error message please

Comment: NameError in TestingsController#index
uninitialized constant Testing::Tokened

Extracted source (around line #2):
1
2
3
                
class Testing < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Tokened
end

Rails.root: /home/patrick/certifications

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/models/testing.rb:2:in `<class:Testing>'
app/models/testing.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/controllers/testings_controller.rb:7:in `index'
Request

Parameters:

None

Comment: Where do you have the `tokened.rb` file? Is Rails loading it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all it should be lowercased: `tokened.rb`. But where is your file? It should be here `modules/concerns/tokened.rb`.